# Source code Implementation of connected_components(G) function in networkx python library

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using networkx library in Python.

There is a function in networkx named connected_components(G) which outputs the list of connected components in graph G.

Please provide source code implementation of this function of networkx library.

I don't need Pseudocode, I need the source code implementation of this function using networkx library and Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for this function (minus docstring) is:

```
def connected_components(G):
    seen = set()
    for v in G:
        if v not in seen:
            c = set(_plain_bfs(G, v))
            yield c
            seen.update(c)
```

This can be found (including docstring) [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/connected.html#connected_components).

You can get there by simply clicking the green `[source]` link on the documentation page for this function (this will also work if you're interested in source code for any other function in the future). This documentation page for this particular function can be found [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html).

Comment: In the code, what is _plain_bfs_ ?
As i cannot find any function named "_plain_bfs" in networkx

Comment: That function is defined in exactly the same file (so you can find it in the same source file I linked to in the answer). You can find it by searching for its name using Ctrl+F in your browser (it happens to be all the way at the bottom of the page in this case).

Comment: Yes checked it. Thank you :)

Comment: @Zero_Cool - that underscore at the start means that it is an intentionally undocumented function.  The developer writes the module with the understanding that a user won't use it (it's possible to go ahead and use it, but it comes with the risk that the developer could modify that code in any way and has no obligation to make sure that it behaves the same in future versions).

Comment: @Joel - Thank you for explanation.